# How to combine the Classes of OddArr and Bubble Sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

Please Help. I am trying combine 2 classes (bubblesort4 and OddArrSe3), to get the answer from bubblesort4 to appear on OddArrSe3, such as on `System.out.println ("Bubble Sort : ")`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;

public class OddArrSe3
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        int[] array_sort = {10,41,21,24,34,15,40,12,32,23,13,25,30,31,22,33,14,35,20,11};

        ArrayList<Integer> OddArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> EvenArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i : array_sort)    
        {
            if ((i & 1) == 1) 
            {
                OddArr.add(i);
            } 
            else 
            {
                EvenArr.add(i);
            }
         }

         Collections.sort(OddArr);
         Collections.sort(EvenArr);
         System.out.println("Odd:" + OddArr);
         System.out.println("Even:" + EvenArr);

          int OddArr2[] = {11, 13, 15, 21, 23, 25, 31, 33, 35, 41};
          int toSearch = 31;  

          int EvenArr2[] = {10, 12, 14, 20, 22, 24, 30, 32, 34, 40};
          int toSearch2 = 32;

          LinearSearch4 linearSearch = new LinearSearch4();  
          BinarySearch4 binarySearch = new BinarySearch4();  
          Bubblesort4 bubblesSort = new BubbleSort4();

          System.out.println("Linear Search Index : "  
          + linearSearch.searchLinear(OddArr2, toSearch));  
          System.out.println("Binary Search Index : "  
          + binarySearch.searchBinary(EvenArr2, toSearch2)); 
          System.out.println ("Bubble Sort : ") 
        }
 }


public class BubbleSort4 
{
     public static void main(String[] args) {

                int intArray[] = new int[]{5,90,35,45,150,3};

                System.out.println("Array Before Bubble Sort");
                for(int i=0; i < intArray.length; i++)
                {
                        System.out.print(intArray[i] + " ");
                }

                bubbleSort(intArray);

                System.out.println("");

                System.out.println("Array After Bubble Sort");
                for(int i=0; i < intArray.length; i++)
                {
                        System.out.print(intArray[i] + " ");
                }

         }

        private static void bubbleSort(int[] intArray) 
        {                            
                int n = intArray.length;
                int temp = 0;

                for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
                {
                        for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++)
                        {

                                if(intArray[j-1] > intArray[j])
                                {

                                        temp = intArray[j-1];
                                        intArray[j-1] = intArray[j];
                                        intArray[j] = temp;
                                }

                        }
                }    
        }
 }
```

Comment: missing ; after System.out.println ("Bubble Sort : ")

Comment: Good lord, please read the naming conventions for Java.

Comment: "I tried but I keep ...." - What exactly did you try? What was the exact error message you were getting?

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println ("Bubble Sort : ")
```

change it to

```
System.out.println ("Bubble Sort : ");
```

Comment: Perhaps this is one of the many errors in the code....

Comment: This is the one he was referring to.

Comment: Tahnks for the help, but I was hoping to get the answer from the bubble sprt to appear on System.out.println ("Bubble Sort : ");